# cannot execute javascript code in a jupyter notebook

Tags: javascript, jupyter-notebook

I'm working on a custom jupyter notebook ui using the jupyterlab APIs. However, I am running into an issue where I am not able to execute javascript code on my custom frontend. I am not sure why that is. I am able to run this magic command on the default jupyter lab ui and on the classic jupyter notebook ui (on the same server image that is running all 3 of these interfaces)

I've tried to "trust" this notebook, but it still doesn't allow me to execute js through the magic functions.

How can I enable inline javascript to be executable in a jupyter notebook? Surely it must be possible, but the jupyter documentation doesn't mention anything about enabling/disabling magic javascript

[jupyter magic documentations](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html)

[image]

Comment: what if you change `window.alert` to `console.log`?

Comment: It'll show me the same thing. Javascript is completely disabled (i don't see `hi` in the console)

Comment: See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/unable-to-use-javascript-magic-function/13641/2?u=fomightez) and the following discussion for my possible insight.